# How to number a printed dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

```
ice_cream = {'I Vanilla': [1.25, 10], 'I Chocolate': [1.25, 8], 'I Cookies & Cream': [1.51, 15]}  #{ice cream type: price, quantity}

def show_inventory():
    print('\nINVENTORY\n')
    print('Ice Cream')
    for key, value in ice_cream.items():
        print("{:15} \t {:5} \t {}".format(key, *value))
```

This is my result

```
I Vanilla             1.25   10
I Chocolate           1.25   8
I Cookies & Cream     1.51   15
```

However, I would like for it to look like this...

```
1 ) I Vanilla             1.25   10
2 ) I Chocolate           1.25   8
3 ) I Cookies & Cream     1.51   15
4 ) future additions
5 ) future additions
```

Comment: `for n,(key,value) in enumerate(ice_cream.items(),1):...`

Comment: I'm getting the same result

Comment: I assume you used `n` in the body of the loop. If you did not, surely you would get the same results.

Comment: `for (key, value) in enumerate(ice_cream.items(), 1):
        print("{} \t {:5} \t {}".format(key, *value))`                                                                    this is what the updated code looks like and the result is                                 `Ice Cream
1   I Vanilla   [1.25, 10]
2   I Chocolate   [1.25, 8]
3   I Cookies & Cream   [1.51, 15]`

Comment: It's not the code that I suggested

Comment: if i copy the code from your initial reply, it produces the same result i started with

Comment: Once again, you have to update the body of the loop to make use of `n`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused what you mean by that. Update the body of what loop?

Answer (score 0):

What DyZ meant was this

```
ice_cream = {'I Vanilla': [1.25, 10], 'I Chocolate': [1.25, 8], 'I Cookies & Cream': [1.51, 15]}  #{ice cream type: price, quantity}

def show_inventory():
    print('\nINVENTORY\n')
    print('Ice Cream')
    for n, (key, value) in enumerate(ice_cream.items(), 1):
        print("{}) {:15} \t {:5} \t {}".format(n, key, *value))
```